# Can't ignore some binary files under one folder by using git-lfs

Tags: git, git-lfs, unreal

Here is my `.gitattributes` file.

```
[attr]lock filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=binary -text lockable
[attr]lockonly lockable
[attr]lfs filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=binary -text
[attr]lfstext filter=lfs diff=lfstext merge=lfstext -text
# Unreal Engine file types.
*.uasset lock
*.umap lock
*.locres lfs
*.locmeta lfs
# Steam Audio files
*.phononscene lfs
*.probebox lfs
*.probebatch lfs
*.bakedsources lfs
# Binaries
*.exe lfs
*.dll lfs
*.rcc lfs
# FMOD
*.bank lfs
*.wav lfs
*.mp3 lfs
*.ogg lfs
*.flac lfs
# Icons
*.png lfs
*.ico lfs
*.icns lfs
# Movies
*.bk2 lfs
```

I already add this line in my `.gitignore`.

```
# git-lfs plugin
Plugins/UEGitPlugin-*/*
```

It ignores everything except four binary files. It seems like it was tracked by git lfs.

Run the command `git ls-files . --exclude-standard --others`. Get the output.

```
Config/DefaultEditor.ini
Config/DefaultEngine.ini
Config/DefaultGame.ini
Config/DefaultInput.ini
PCGLearn.uproject
Plugins/UEGitPlugin-3.13/git-lfs
Plugins/UEGitPlugin-3.13/git-lfs-mac-amd64
Plugins/UEGitPlugin-3.13/git-lfs-mac-arm64
Plugins/UEGitPlugin-3.13/git-lfs.exe
Source/PCGLearn.Target.cs
Source/PCGLearn/PCGLearn.Build.cs
Source/PCGLearn/PCGLearn.cpp
Source/PCGLearn/PCGLearn.h
Source/PCGLearn/PCGLearnGameModeBase.cpp
Source/PCGLearn/PCGLearnGameModeBase.h
Source/PCGLearnEditor.Target.cs
```

Add the `Plugins/UEGitPlugin-3.13/git-lfs !filter !diff !merge -text` to `.gitattributes` didn't work. The command `git config lfs.fetchexclude "Plugins/UEGitPlugin-3.13/*"` still didn't work.

Here is my photo of Rider's git tools.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very weird. After I changed `Plugins/UEGitPlugin-*/*` into `Plugins/UEGitPlugin-*/`, the problem was solved.